# approximate string matching on condition of a match in a separate field in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes from which I would like to carry out approximate string matching.

```
> df1       
Source      Name                                 Country
 A          Glen fiddich                        United Kingdom
 A          Talisker dark storm                 United Kingdom
 B          johnney walker                      United states
 D          veuve clicquot brut                 France
 E          nicolas feuillatte brut             France
 C          glen morangie                       united kingdom
 B          Talisker 54 degrees                 United kingdom
 F          Talisker dark storm                 United states
```

The second data frame:

```
> df2   
Source              Name                        Country
  A         smirnoff ice                        Russia
  A         Talisker daek strome                United Kingdom
  B         johnney walker                      United states
  D         veuve clicquot brut                 Australia
  E         nicolea feuilate brut               Italy
  C         glen morangie                       united kingdom
  B         Talisker 54 degrees                 United kingdom
```

the key column for the approximate matching between the two data frames is "Name". Because of the relationship in the columns for the observations, It is important to select the approximate matches that also have a match on the "country" column. The extract of the code I am using is below:

```
dist.mat <- stringdistmatrix(tolower(df1$title), tolower(df2$title), method = "jw",
            nthread = getOption("sd_num_thread"))  

min.dist <- apply(dist.mat, 1, min)

matched <- data.frame(df1$title, 
           as.character(apply(dist.mat, 1, function(x) df2$title[which(x == min(x))])),
           apply(dist.mat, 1, which.min), "jw", apply(dist.mat, 1, min)) 

colnames(matched) <- c("to_be_matched", "closest_match", "index_closest_match",
                     "distance_method", "distance")
```

The code above only executes approximate match between df1 and df2 based on data in the "Name" column. What I want to do is have the approximate match on "Name" column selected on the condition that for the two values, there is a match on the "Country" column.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [fuzzywuzzy library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy), which has excellent fuzzy text matching capabilities.  Then I would iterate through the unique countries and look for matches that pass a certain fuzz threshold score, like the following:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process
matches = []
for country in df1['Country'].unique().tolist():
    dfm1 = df1[df1['Country'] == country]
    dfm2 = df2[df2['Country'] == country]
    candidates = dfm2['Name'].tolist()
    matches.append(dfm1['Name'].apply(lambda x: x, process.extractOne(x, candidates, score_cutoff=90)))
```

You can tweak the `scorer` input in order to get the matches the way you like it.

Comment: Just judging by the title, I think the OP was looking for an R-based solution.

Comment: It originally had a python tag I thought--my fault.